# Asynchronous Generators in UseEffect - how to unsubscribe from updates

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, generator, use-effect

I've been playing with using async generators in Typescript React apps.

I created the following component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const delay = (ms : number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const fetchData = async (count : number, url: string) => { 
    await delay(1000);
    const title : string = await fetch(`${url}/${count}`).then(response => response.json()).then(data => data.title)
    return title; 
}

const asyncGenerator = async function* () { 
    let count : number = 1;
    const url : string = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    while(true) { 
        yield fetchData(count, url)
        count++;
    }

}

const UseEffectComponent = () => { 
    const [titles, setTitles] = useState<string[]>([])

 
    useEffect(() => { 
        (async () => { 
            for await (const title of asyncGenerator()) { 
                setTitles(t => [...t, title])
            }
        })();
        
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {titles.map(t => <p>{t}</p>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UseEffectComponent;
```

Essentially, I've created a stream of post titles, which are supplied by the `asyncGenerator` function, which will fetch data from the placeholder API every second by calling `fetchData` which uses `delay` to introduce an artificial `1000ms` delay.

I'm curious what is the best way to read this data from the stream in the component itself. My current implementation using `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    (async () => { 
        for await (const title of asyncGenerator()) { 
            setTitles(t => [...t, title])
        }
    })();
```

has no cleanup code - meaning this stream will continue to supply data even when the component is unmounted. I'm not sure what the best way to fix this would be though. Can I exit this `for of` loop when the component unmounts? Or is there a better way to consume data from my stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `isMounted` to check component is unmounted or not.

```
useEffect(() => { 
  let isMounted = true;
  (async () => {
      for await (const title of asyncGenerator()) { 
        if(!isMounted){
          break;
        }
        setTitles(t => [...t, title])
      }
  })();  

  return () => {
    isMounted = false;
  };
}, [])
```